# Populate Cell with standard wording when another cell returns anything other than zero

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am currently trying to work out how to populate a cell when the result in another cell is above or below zero.

I.e. If cell A1 returns a result greater than or less than zero I would like cell B2 to return the wording `<<<<<< Error - Cell must equal zero.`

Not sure if it helps but the figure in cell A1 is produced as a result of the difference between two other cells. E.g. formula in cell A1 is `D2 - D5`.

Disclaimer: Pretty much a complete novice with VBA. Experience includes about 6 If/Elseif statements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to achieve the desired output.

Place the following formula in B1 ( if you want to display the error msg in B1 depending upon the output returned by the formula in A1)

```
=A1
```

And then apply the following custom formatting to the B1.

```
"<<<<<< Error - Cell must equal zero.";"<<<<<< Error - Cell must equal zero.";
```

This will produce the following output in B1.
[image]

[image]

[image]